# Error while installing 'Live Server' extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

> Error while installing 'Live Server' extension. Please check the log for more details.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoH0g.jpg)

I tried looking for solutions but most of them would be for windows version.
I have macOS could you give me a detailed solution for this issue .I tried installing live server and open browser same error message was popping each time.

Comment: What VS Code version are you on?

Comment: Version: 1.80.1

Comment: show the log it mentions

Comment: I am new to these things ,can u please brief me about what r u asking exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Download manually...
Immediately after downloading comeback to vscode there shows install vsix file . Click on it and upload a file which u have installed manually.

Comment: I have done these now thank you so much . But i wanted to know why it’s not working now and what are the changes should I do so it starts working like before.